# How can I set comments in YAML translation file?

Tags: parsing, yaml, comments, symfony-3.4

Symfony throws a parsing exception when it tries to parse a comment in the begining of the file. For more explanation down there I put a example code:

```
#This is a comment
m:
  subtitles:
    movie: 'Movie subtitle'
```

The entire exception is: `"ParseException: Unable to parse in "<Directory path>...\\translations\\messages.es.yml" at line 1 (near "#This is a comment").`

When I remove that first line (the entire comment) it works. I also tried with a space between `#` character and the comment title:

```
# This is a comment
```

Comment: This is rather a bug report that should be directed towards Symfony than a question that should be asked here. Your comment certainly is valid YAML syntax.

Comment: Thanks @flyx for your comment. Certainly I'll do that